# How many digits should I round recurring numbers to in css?

Tags: css

Let's say I want to set an element to have be 2/3 width of the page.

We could use something like:

```
width: 66.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666%
```

I imagine at a certain point that the browser will stop taking note of the digits, but at what point is this?

Are there any more things we should be aware of when using recurring decimals in css?

Comment: One or two digits after the radix should be enough. That offers sufficient precision already. Think about this: NASA uses only up to 15 digits for PI to send things to space. You can also use `calc(100% / 1.5)` and let it determine the precision itself.

Comment: use calc() ....

Comment: Here's a good article that explains Browser Rounding and Fractional Pixels in detail: https://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Answer (score 4):

you can just use this:
`width: calc(100% / 3);` or `width: calc(200% / 3)` (in your case)

I usually round the value to one decimal place. I think, that's enough.

Answer (score 1):

A 5k screen is 5120 pixels wide. Taking 0.6, then 0.66 etc gives:

```
5120 * 0.6 = 3072.0
5120 * 0.66 = 3379.20
5120 * 0.666 = 3409.920
5120 * 0.6666 = 3412.9920
5120 * 0.66666 = 3413.29920
5120 * 0.666666 = 3413.329920
```

I'll leave it to you to work out if it's worth a few pixels either way between 0.666 and above, or even if 34 pixels is acceptable between 0.66 & 0.666.